Making portable c++ shared library for older machines
I have developed code using
g++ -std=c++23, using features of this new standard. The output is a shared library which is used by a binary executable, and which would also be called as the backend from a python gui frontend. My development machine has g++ 13.2.0, and the application should work on a machine with g++ 9.4.0 offering -std=c++17, and GLIBC_2.30 maximum.  The code can not be compiled on the target machine, and upgrading the target machine is not an option.
I am trying to make the compiled binaries (the .so file and the executable) portable. Using the -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc options to the linker bake this code into the compiled .so and binaries. However, as is generally suggested, libc is still statically linked, and I get /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by libmysharedlib.so) errors.
I tried to copy the libc.so.6 and libpthread.so from the target machine to the compile machine and link against them using -nolibc /path/to/target_machine_libs/libc.so.6 /path/to/target_machine_libs/libpthread.so, but it does not work: the target machine's libc.so.6 is lacking some symbols that libstdc++ is referring to: __isoc23_strtol, _dl_find_object, fstat64, __libc_single_threaded, stat, arc4random, lstat. (I checked _dl_find_object for example, and it is indeed defined in the compile machine's libc.so.6, but not in the target machine's libc.so.6).
Is there any way to make this work? I am pretty sure that copying libc.so.6 from the compile machine to the target machine would not work (especially when loading the .so file into the python program, the host's native libc and the ported one would collide?).
How do software developers manage to install their software on older machines at all? Naive guess would be that they compile it with several old versions of g++ and the associated libs, and choose the version which fits the target machine, but it doesn't work if they want to use a decent, recent version of g++. New versions of the compiler which speak the recent C++ dialect have their c++ libs referring to symbols that are only available in recent versions of libc, it seems.
[UPDATE]
I gave the musl cross-compiler a chance. I used the same version of g++ on my system, following the tip here: https://github.com/crazywhalecc/static-php-cli/issues/345

add a gcc-13.2.0.tar.xz.sha1 in the hashes folder containing "5f95b6d042fb37d45c6cbebfc91decfbc4fb493c  gcc-13.2.0.tar.xz" (without the quotes).

It compiled fine.
I am trying to compile/link my shared library with these options:
CXX = /home/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/bin/x86_64-linux-musl-g++
LD = /home/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/bin/x86_64-linux-musl-g++

compile:
$(CXX) -fPIC -Wno-interference-size -std=c++23 -pthread -O2 -o XXX.o XXX.C

link:
$(LD) -shared -o libmylib.so XXX.o --static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -L/home/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/x86_64-linux-musl/lib -l:libc.a

Compilation works but upon linking I get the following error:
/user-data/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /home/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/x86_64-linux-musl/lib/libc.a(strerror.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.errmsgstr' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/user-data/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /home/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/x86_64-linux-musl/lib/libc.a(abort.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against hidden symbol `__abort_lock' can not be used when making a shared object
/user-data/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /home/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/x86_64-linux-musl/lib/libc.a(atexit.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss.lock' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/user-data/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /home/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/x86_64-linux-musl/lib/libc.a(exit.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against undefined hidden symbol `__fini_array_start' can not be used when making a shared object
/user-data/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /home/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/x86_64-linux-musl/lib/libc.a(lite_malloc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss.lock' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/user-data/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /home/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/x86_64-linux-musl/lib/libc.a(inet_ntop.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.inet_ntop.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/user-data/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /home/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/x86_64-linux-musl/lib/libc.a(fork.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.atfork_locks' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/user-data/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /home/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/x86_64-linux-musl/lib/libc.a(system.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.system.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/user-data/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /home/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/x86_64-linux-musl/lib/libc.a(block.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.all_mask' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/user-data/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /home/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/x86_64-linux-musl/lib/libc.a(sigaction.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss.handler_set' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/user-data/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /home/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/x86_64-linux-musl/lib/libc.a(vsnprintf.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.text.sn_write' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/user-data/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /home/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/x86_64-linux-musl/lib/libc.a(mktemp.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.mktemp.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/user-data/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /home/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/x86_64-linux-musl/lib/libc.a(lock_ptc.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss.lock' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/user-data/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /home/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/x86_64-linux-musl/lib/libc.a(vmlock.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss.vmlock' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/user-data/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /home/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/x86_64-linux-musl/lib/libc.a(clock_gettime.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.cgt_init.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/user-data/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /home/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/x86_64-linux-musl/lib/libc.a(intscan.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata.table' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/user-data/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /home/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/x86_64-linux-musl/lib/libc.a(_Fork.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against hidden symbol `__abort_lock' can not be used when making a shared object
/user-data/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /home/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/x86_64-linux-musl/lib/libc.a(posix_spawn.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata.child' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/user-data/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /home/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/x86_64-linux-musl/lib/libc.a(vfprintf.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata.pop_arg' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/user-data/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /home/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/x86_64-linux-musl/lib/libc.a(__init_tls.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against hidden symbol `__thread_list_lock' can not be used when making a shared object
/user-data/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: /home/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/x86_64-linux-musl/lib/libc.a(ofl.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss.ofl_lock' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/user-data/barna/progs/musl/musl-cross-make-master/output/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-musl/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-linux-musl/bin/ld: final link failed: nonrepresentable section on output

There seems to be an idential problem on SO: musl fails to link libc.a into shared library
But it is not quite clear to me how to proceed. There the accepted answer is to build musl with no asm enabled. How is this done? Is this the right way to go?
Thank you
Best regards
Daniel


Is there any way to make this work?

Yes.

Set up a docker container with GLIBC matching your target environment (2.30 here).
In that container, build and install GCC-13.2 (from source).
Using just installed GCC-13.2, compile and link your shared library with -static-libstdc++ and -static-libgcc.


How do software developers manage to install their software on older machines at all?

Usually by building (in a container) using the oldest GLIBC and GCC they want to support (GCC doesn't have to be old if you build it from source).
P.S. Copying libc.so.6 from target to build machine can not work for reasons explained here.
P.P.S. Using Musl will not work unless you build everything (your binary, and python) that loads your shared library with Musl as well.

Hello, thanks, it is getting clear now. Sorry, I never had to dig so deep. I think this project is just offering this solution: https://github.com/AmanoTeam/obggcc/ (but one can not be sure if there is no malware in it...)
